# iOS Local authentication fallback to passcode for older devices?

Tags: ios, fallback, passcode, localauthentication

I have recently started using **Local Authentication (LA)** and it all works nicely on devices that support biometric authentication (touch id):

To allow the LA falling back to passcode when the user fails the first fingerprint scan I just pass the `LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthentication` policy.

But when I do the same for older devices (with no touch id or face id support) LA instead falls back to some generic password UI. Also, it seems I can submit any password and get a **Success**.

1. Is there a way to force LA to immediately prompt the Passcode UI instead?
2. Which password is LA requesting?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was just an iOS simulator behavior. I dug up and old iPhone 5 and the behavior is then what I expected: When biometric authentication is not supported iOS automatically falls back to requesting the device passcode.

In conclusion: Avoid using simulators all together to learn/test Local Authentication.